# When performing matrix calculations in python, different values are calculated when entering list calculations at once and individually

Tags: list, matrix

I am writing the Nelder-mead algorithm myself, but when calculating the matrix, a completely different value is calculated when entering the list calculation at once and when entering it individually. I don't know why different values come out.
Upper code is no problem case (but not general calculation), and below code is problem case (it's general calculation).

```
    # Step 3. Reflection
    # No problem case
    xr=[x0[0] + a * (x0[0] - x[Ns][0]),
        x0[1] + a * (x0[1] - x[Ns][1])]
    
    fr = func(xr)

    if fr >= f[0] and fr < f[Ns-1]:
        x[Ns] = xr
        f[Ns] = fr
```

```
    # Step 3. Reflection
    # Problem case
    for i in range(Ns):
        xr[i] = x0[i] + a * (x0[i] - x[Ns][i])
    
    fr = func(xr)

    if fr >= f[0] and fr < f[Ns-1]:
        x[Ns] = xr
        f[Ns] = fr
```

I've been looking for the difference between the two codes, but I can't seem to find any clues.